# How to configure Update Method for object data source in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview with all columns read only except one. I want to configure the update method for the object data source to update only one column. The code i have written works when i make all columns editable but fails when i try to make only one column editable. Can someone tell me what i should do?

Answer (score 0):

Try to figure out what arguments the Object datasource is trying to give to your method when updating. It might not pass the uneditable ones, and this could be the cause of the failure.

Comment: Yes all the uneditable integer values are passed as 0 and strings as null